# Отчёт запроса PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, report

Как видно из рисунка ниже, названия столбцов в сгенерированном
отчете не понятны, особенно это касается столбцов,
как сделать изменения  таким образом, чтобы указать названия Contract, Date, Total
amount и Total cost для соответствующих столбцов.

[image: Рисунок 1.1]

process request to export report into the Excel document

```
if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "export") {
    $filename = "report_contracts_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

    $flag = false;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "CALL sp_contract_total('2018-01-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (!$flag) {
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
        }

        array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
    }

    exit;
}

function cleanData(&$str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);

    if (strstr($str, '"')) {
        $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил не работать с PHP а назначить название столбцам таблицы представления

BEGIN
    SELECT contract.contract_number **AS "Contract Number"**, contract.contract_date **AS "Date"**,
        SUM(supplied.supplied_amount) **AS "Total Amount"**, SUM(supplied.supplied_amount * supplied.supplied_cost) **AS "Total Sum"**
    FROM contract LEFT JOIN supplied ON contract.contract_number = supplied.contract_number
    WHERE contract.contract_date BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
    GROUP BY contract.contract_number, contract.contract_date;
END

Результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]